# TAG Dupes except with MIN DATE

Tags: excel-formula, duplicates

COL A
1
2
3
1

COL B
2
3
4
2

COL C
3
3
2
3

COL D
4/1
4/1
4/1
4/2

DUPE?
N
N
N
Y

Looking at the above example, how would I write a formula for column 5 (DUPE?) that looks at the first 3 columns and then, if COL D is the MIN Date, it does not consider a DUPE, but any dates after it, it is a dupe?

I have IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, B2, C:C, C2)>1,"Y","N")

but, it is tagging the 1st one as a duplicate, also.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is sorted on dates,

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1,$C$1:C1,C1)>1,"Y","N")
```

[image]